# can I debug modules step by step in Spyder?

Tags: python-3.x, spyder, ipdb

Debugging works step by step only in the main script. Can I somehow see what is happening in the functions from the imported modules without moving their contents in my main script?

For example I would like to see what's inside **a,b&c** variables.

module.py:

```
def a_b():
    a=1
    b=2
    c=a+b
    return c
```

My main script:

```
from module import a_b
x=2
y=3
z=x*y
print (z)
print (a_b())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click the Step into function (CTRL+F11)